# Silverlight simple map tool with zoom and pushpins

Tags: silverlight, dictionary

I'm very new to Silverlight so bear with me.  I need to implement a web page with a zoom-able map of Europe.  I need the map to contain pushpins or such like which are generated from a database of lon/lat locations.

If the user hovers over a pin then some data should appear about the location and then if the user clicks on a location and be given detailed information (images, text and other live data) next to the map.  Originally I was looking at google maps or bing but as this is to be used commercially and is not going to be public, I am unable to use them for licencing reasons.

I've looked into using [deepzoom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645050%28v=vs.95%29.aspx), which seems perfect but I cannot find any decent ways of adding the pushpins.

So essentially can anyone suggest a tool to allow me to make a zoomable map (I can supply a map image) which can have pushpins generated which can be selected by the user through highlight or click

Many thanks,

Cap

Comment: Do you absolutely positively have to do it with silverlight? Sane individuals would use OpenLayers and JavaScript, to make something that would be more cross-platform than silverlight ever will be. I'm guessing everything else is going to be silverlight for some strange reason, but if you are new to it, why did you get employed to do it?

Comment: Yes sadly, I originally wrote it using open layers.  It only took a few days to get all the functionality up and running, I was very pleased... Only THEN was I told that we'd said we'd do it in Silverlight and it's supposed to be some kind of 'ground breaking' thing for the company.  As it'll be used to show prospective clients that we can work in silverlight, I can't risk building bits in other languages.  Thanks for the suggestion though, great minds think alike it seems :)

Answer (score 1):

Use [Bing Maps Silverlight Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee681884.aspx).
[Here](http://www.microsoft.com/maps/isdk/silverlight/) is preview from Microsoft.
You need Developers Account for using it. Account is free. You can get it [here](http://www.microsoft.com/maps/developers/web.aspx).
Bing Maps control is simple to use, supports [pushpins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2162626/silverlight-add-pushpin-to-bing-maps-via-c) and deep zoom.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  Sadly as the site is to be non-pubic facing and is for commercial use, I need to pay for it's use.  At the moment I don't think that is an option open to me.  So I'm after a free solution.  Thanks anyway

Comment: May be **[Free Silverlight mapping with Bing maps and OpenStreetMap?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4724004/free-silverlight-mapping-with-bing-maps-and-openstreetmap)** post from SO will be helpful for you.